# Error in siunitx with TeXlive 2012? 'missing $' with inter-unit-product option

Tags: texlive, siunitx

With the latest TeXlive update to the 2012 version, for some reason I am getting `missing $ inserted` messages, when using the `inter-unit-product` option for `\si`.

For example, this is taken directly from the PDF documentation:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
    \si[inter-unit-product={}\cdot{}]{\farad\squared\lumen\candela}
\]
\end{document}
```

and it fails to compile for me with the above error.

Comment: In math mode, that is.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: Not really necessary here, but sure.

Comment: This seems to work fine `\si[inter-unit-product={$\cdot$}]{\farad\squared\lumen\candela}` with TeXLive2011.  Or if you want the extra spacing use `[inter-unit-product={${}\cdot{}$}]`. TeXLive2011 even requires this -- perhaps an error in the documentation?

Comment: Or the method that they wrote word-for-word in the manual, using the `ensuremath` command.

I also found that it works if you surround the whole command in `$`s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks both you and I were looking at an older version of the documentation. I just downloaded the latest version (2012-07-22) which suggests the use of

```
\si[inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]
```

which yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
    \si[inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{\farad\squared\lumen\candela}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow...this is a *legitimate* use of `\ensuremath`!

Comment: @RyanReich: Yeah was about to replace it with `$` fearing @egreg's wrath :-), but then realized in this case he would probably let it slide since you may want to use units outside of math mode.

Comment: Even better: you have *no way* of knowing how the inter-unit product is actually produced internally.  This is truly a "just use this math symbol" situation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a minor update! In the most recently updated version (10/28/2014) of `siunitx`, this code works, and produces the correct symbol and spacing.

```
\usepackage[inter-unit-product=\cdot]{siunitx}
```

The code from the answer here:

```
\usepackage[inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{siunitx}
```

no longer seems to work, and will throw an error about a missing `$` or `}`. I discovered this quite by accident, and thought I would share.

### Edit

Here is an MWE, asked for in the comments:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\si{\joule\per\cm\squared\per\hour}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tested this, and here is what I found: using `\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}` did work, and produced the correct spacing and symbols. However, loading the option like so: `\usepackage[inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{siunitx}` does not work. This produces the errors described above. I will post an MWE above.

Comment: I _very_ strongly discourage load time options for `siunitx`: the way that the LaTeX kernel handles such things means that expansion can lead to issues. `\sisetup` is _strongly_ preferred.